# GWT RootPanel vs RootLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt

I understand that officially GWT recommends using the newer RootLayoutPanel but some posts on the internet claims that for some web applications it is better to use the RootPanel.
How can one decide which one to use?
Is there any different use cases for each? (or every requirement can be satisfied with either)

Comment: I so far made good experiences with RootLayoutPanel. What do these Internet posts claim?

Comment: [http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/5f68621da14f034d](Here) is an example of such post in which they discus the type of web application to use with RootPanel or RootLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`RootLayoutPanel` can't be better. It is just different.

`RootPanel` allows you to add widgets to the page (basically you can use some html element on the page as root widget). You can define multiple `RootPanel's` in the same application.

`RootLayoutPanel` behaves a little bit differently, it always tries to fill all the available size in the window, so the content inside of the panel will perfectly fit the browser window size. It will also track the size of the window, and will resize child elements accordingly (if they support it). Also `RootLayoutPanel` will try to attach itself directly to the `<body> element`, e.g. you can't choose which html element on the page will become a "starting point".

So, depending on what you want to do you can choose `RootPanel` or `RootLayoutPanel`.

Comment: mmm thanks but I would like to understand how choosing one over the other will (just throwing ideas) 1. make me write more code for certain application type or feature. 2. make it impossible to do some UI or UX feature. etc...