# Gwt UI binder html, css

Tags: html, css, gwt

Hi I am new at Gwt and I am trying to develop a web application.  For that reason I use html and css in the ui binder for the desing.  In my project there is two page design with ui binder.  In the first page I use html and css for design be better in ui binder and in the second page I just use ui binder and I don't use any html or css

After all when I want to pass one page to another I am using
`RootPanel.get().clear(); RootPanel.get().add(new SurveyApp())`  in order to go `SurveyApp()` page.

However , because of the first page design , which I use html and css in ui binder, my `SurveyApp()` page design is broken.  Some of them say that `RootPanel.get().clear();` doesn't the whole Html and for that I use `RootPanel.get().getElement().setInnerHTML("");`

But after I use this code, noting display in my page and my `SurveyApp()` page couldn't display the page.

Please Can you help me

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more normal to use something like SimplePanel, as the root widget of your app, then change what is in that...

So you just add your SimplePanel once to the RootPanel and never again.

btw You might want to look at [GWT RootPanel vs RootLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160210/gwt-rootpanel-vs-rootlayoutpanel) depending on what form of layout you want to use.

That is the way the Activity/Places works. Most apps will want some sort of history support so end up using that.